# Cordova iOS camera plugin returns empty snapshop

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, canvas

I have a simple Cordova based APP, I'm using camera and file plugin.
I take picture, draw on a canvas, user can add some images over and save the image.

On android everythings work ok, but on iOS the picture that I take its empty and cant be drawed on canvas, on XCode console I recive:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

My camera code is:

```
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function(imageData) {

                bgSrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;
                bgImg.setAttribute('src', bgSrc);

                app.drawEditor(bgImg);
            },
            function(message) {
                alert('Failed because: ' + message);
                app.addClass('Home');
                app.drawMenu();
            }, {
                quality: 50,
                correctOrientation: true,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 720,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            });
```

**Note**: I'm using the lastest version of cordova and the latest version of camera plugin from github.

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: I think it's a bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8234 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7641

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you:

```
                 function captureProfilePhoto(exec)
                      {
                              alert("captureProfilePhoto");
                             //alert("check");
                          navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){
                            exec(imageURI);
                            }, function(message){
                            alert("No attachment added");
                            //alert(labels.get("VPCS_GLOBAL_FAILURE_REASON_"+language)+" : " + message);
                            exec(-1);
                            }, {
                            quality : 100,
                            destinationType: navigator.camera.FILE_URI,
                            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                            targetWidth:960,
                            targetHeight:640,
                            correctOrientation: true,
                            allowEdit : true,
                            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions });


                      }
```

//calling the above method with ID:

```
                      $("#basicInfoCapturePhoto").click(function(){
                   captureProfilePhoto(function(imageURI){
                      if(imageURI != -1){
                       profileImageURI = imageURI;

                 });
              }

          });
```

Comment: Let me try and get back